# Removing parent element by clicking on div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a form being generated like this

```
        <%for (var i = 0; i < user.categories.length; i++) {%>
        <div class="form-group" id="<%=i %>">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="category<%=i %>name" value="<%=user.categories[i].taskname%>" placeholder = "Enter task name">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="category<%=i %>priority" value="<%=user.categories[i].taskpriority%>" placeholder = "Enter task priority" min="1" max="3">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="category<%=i %>duration" value="<%=user.categories[i].taskduration%>" placeholder = "Enter task duration" min="0" max="24">
        <button class = "delete" id="<%=i %>" type="button">Delete</button>
            <!--<input type="text" class="form-control" name="category<%=i %>" value="<%=user.categories[i] %>"> -->
                            <br>
        </div>
                        <br>

        <%} %>
```

And this script

```
    $(".delete").click(function(){
        var parent = this.parent();
        alert(this.id); 
        parent.empty();


    });
```

I'm creating a delete button with an id i, and I thought that the jquery would grab the element I clicked, then find its parent div and delete the entire div. However, this isn't happening, any ideas why?

Comment: Is not just `parent.remove();` ?

Comment: parent.remove() doesn'twork either

Comment: Ahhhh, you're not wrapping `this`, I believe `this` would give you the pure HTML, try wrapping it in `$(this)`

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing jQuery and plain javascript.  In a jQuery event handler, `this` is a DOM object (not a jQuery object) and a DOM object doesn't have a `.parent()` method.  It has a `.parentNode` property.  If you want to get a jQuery object that you can call the jQuery method `.empty()` on, then you need to use `$(this)` like this:

```
$(".delete").click(function(){
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    parent.empty();
});
```

Or, in a more compact way:

```
$(".delete").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().empty();
});
```

---

Also, `.empty()` will just clear the contents of the parent.  It won't remove the parent, but will remove any child nodes in the parent (e.g. emptying the parent).  If you want to actually remove the parent, you would use `.remove()` like this:

```
$(".delete").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: Also, depends on whether you want to delete the whole container, or just clear the contents on whether `.empty()` or `.remove()` is used.

Comment: @No1_Melman - added info on `.remove()` to my answer.  It isn't entirely clear which the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because `this` statement in the closure isn't a jQuery object. It's just a HTMLElement. So your need to convert `this` into jQuery first to get access to the .parent() method:

```
var parent = jQuery(this).parent();
```